# glutWarpPointer crash

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm following [these](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/index.html) tutorials on modern OpenGL. I've done them up to number 15 "Camera Control - Part 2". The tutorial suggests using glutWarpPointer(). The problem is, my program crashes at that call. This is my code:

```
c_camera::c_camera(int width, int height, const c_vector3f& Pos, const c_vector3f& Target, const c_vector3f& Up){
    m_windowWidth = width;
    m_windowHeight = height;
    m_pos = Pos;

    m_target = Target;
    m_target.Normalize();

    m_up = Up;
    m_up.Normalize();
    Init();
}

void c_camera::Init(){
    c_vector3f HTarget(m_target.x, 0.0, m_target.z);
    HTarget.Normalize();

    if (HTarget.z >= 0.0f){
        if (HTarget.x >= 0.0f){
            m_AngleH = 360.0f - (asin(HTarget.z) TO_DEG);
        } else {
            m_AngleH = 180.0f + (asin(HTarget.z) TO_DEG);
        }
    } else {
        if (HTarget.x >= 0.0f){
            m_AngleH = (asin(-HTarget.z) TO_DEG);
        } else {
            m_AngleH = 90.0f + (asin(-HTarget.z) TO_DEG);
        }
    }

    m_AngleV = -(asin(m_target.y) TO_DEG);

    m_OnUpperEdge = false;
    m_OnLowerEdge = false;
    m_OnLeftEdge = false;
    m_OnRightEdge = false;
    m_mousePos.x = m_windowWidth / 2;
    m_mousePos.y = m_windowHeight / 2;

    cout << "this gets printed just fine" << endl;

    glutWarpPointer(500,400); //program crashes

    cout << "this doesn't get printed" << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something weird here, or if I just have a bad glut version (seems unlikely to me) or if the tutorial is just wrong... Do I need to set up something glut specific before I can call glutWarpPointer()? I am new to glut, and new to modern OpenGL (I learned immediate mode first).
A quick google search didn't help me much. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I am on windows, and I'm using mingw 4.5

Edit2: These are the details windows gives me about the crash:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   modern_opengl.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  51044575
Fault Module Name:  glut32.dll
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 3bea4ff3
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   0000a879
OS Version: 6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1043
Additional Information 1:   5861
Additional Information 2:   5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
Additional Information 3:   f3d5
Additional Information 4:   f3d5be0cad2787556264647dc02181c3

Edit3: This is my call stack:
0 1000A879  glutWarpPointer() (C:\Windows\system\glut32.dll:??)
1 004033FB  c_camera::Init(this=0x4aa0e0) (C:\CodeBlocks\projects\modern_opengl\c_camera.cpp:50)
2 00403164  c_camera::c_camera(this=0x4aa0e0, width=800, height=600, Pos=..., Target=..., Up=...) (C:\CodeBlocks\projects\modern_opengl\c_camera.cpp:18)
3 00402F4B  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) (C:\CodeBlocks\projects\modern_opengl\main.cpp:55)
4 00403004  *GLOBAL*_sub_I_vertices() (C:\CodeBlocks\projects\modern_opengl\main.cpp:177)
5 0043595B  __do_global_ctors() (../mingw/gccmain.c:59)
6 00401098  __mingw_CRTStartup() (../mingw/crt1.c:236)
7 00401284  mainCRTStartup() (../mingw/crt1.c:264)

Comment: You should call `glutInit` at the beginning of your program. Don't have any more ideas unless you give more information about the crash.

Comment: @yiding I did that, it's covered in the earlier tutorials. I don't know how I could gather more information about the crash, it just gives me the famous windows error "this program has stopped working" so, which usually indicates a memory acces violation. I will edit the question with the error details windows gives me.

Comment: Have you tried running under the gdb that comes with mingw?

Comment: @yiding I have not, I don't use mingw directly, I'm using code::blocks, and just set the default compiler to my mingw install. Is it possible to use the mingw debugger when I run my program from code::blocks? If yes, how?

Comment: Code::Blocks might have a gdb front end built in http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: @yiding I think I found it, not sure though, I never use debuggers. <3 printf() :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function seems to be in c_camera::Init, which seems to be called before `main` probably due to it being instantiated as a global object (globals are constructed before `main` is entered). You should delay glut calls till after you enter `main` and called `glutInit` is called.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much :) I never would have thought of that. I indeed instatiated my camera object outside main in the global namespace.